# customListView of checkbox and textview ,how to sum value of textview checked?

Tags: android, listview

I have a customListView with checkbox and textview and i woul like to sum the value that are checked and show it on the textview.

this is my code:

**row2.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:padding="1dp" >
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </CheckBox>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_qta1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tv_grm"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/v10000"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/size_edit_M"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_qta2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/v10000"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="@dimen/size_edit_M"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_qta1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_qta1"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tv_qta1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_grm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/grammi"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="@dimen/size_edit_M"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_prodotto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:text="@string/prodotto"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="@dimen/size_edit_M"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cbBox"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_qta2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tv_qta2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**int the actyvity i create the listviecustom**

```
        if(userAdapterRct1 == null){
                    userAdapterRct1 = new ItemsListAdapterRct(getActivity().getBaseContext(), userArrayRct1);
                    userListRct1 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
                    userListRct1.setItemsCanFocus(true);
                    userAdapterRct1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    userListRct1.setAdapter(userAdapterRct1);
                    userAdapterRct1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else
                    userAdapterRct1.notifyDataSetChanged();


     if(userAdapterRct1 != null){
                userListRct1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v,int position, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        RelativeLayout listItem = (RelativeLayout) v;
                        TextView clickedItemView = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_prodotto);
                        CheckBox cbView = (CheckBox) listItem.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);

                        cbView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                            //@Override
                            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                                //Integer rct =  (Integer) buttonView.getTag();    
                                // create the suf of items checked
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
```

how create the sum of item checked?

**ItemsListAdapterRct.java**

```
class ItemsListAdapterRct extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater vi;
    private ArrayList<User> data = new ArrayList<User>();
    Context context;

        public ItemsListAdapterRct(Context context, /*int layoutResourceId,*/ ArrayList<User> data) {
        vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    /** Add white line */
    public void addItem(User item) {
        data.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        User p = getProduct(position);
        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.row2, parent, false);//null);
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_prodotto);
            holder.qty_ing = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_qta1);
            holder.qty_risc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_qta2);
            holder.cbView = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if(holder.name != null) {
            holder.name.setText(data.get(position).getName());
        }
        if(holder.qty_ing != null) {
            holder.qty_ing.setText(String.valueOf(data.get(position).getQtyIng()));
        }
        if(holder.qty_risc != null) {
            holder.qty_risc.setText(String.valueOf(data.get(position).getQtyRis()));
        }
        if(holder.cbView != null) {
            holder.cbView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                //@Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    getProduct((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).box = isChecked;
//
//                    // aggiorno il db
//                    DatabaseHelper dbRcp = new DatabaseHelper(context, ImportFragment.DB_DATABASE_STORE);
//                    int pos  = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
//                    Ricetta p = getProduct(pos);
//                    String box = "0";
//                    if(p.box) box = "1";
//                    long res = dbRcp.update_Riscala(p.id, p.name, "0", box);
//                    // Don't forget to close database connection
//                    dbRcp.closeDB();
                }
            });

            //cbBuy.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);
            holder.cbView.setTag(position);
            holder.cbView.setChecked(p.box);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
    User getProduct(int position) {
        return ((User) getItem(position));
    }
//    /** Sort shopping list by name ascending */
//    public void sortByNameAsc() {
//        Comparator<User> comparator = new Comparator<User>() {
//
//            @Override
//            public int compare(User object1, User object2) {
//                return ((String) object1.getName()).compareTo((String) object2.getName());
//            }
//        };
//        Collections.sort(data, comparator);
//        notifyDataSetChanged();
//    }
//
//    /** Sort shopping list by name descending */
//    public void sortByNameDesc() {
//        Comparator<User> comparator = new Comparator<User>() {
//
//            @Override
//            public int compare(User object1, User object2) {
//                return ((String) object2.getName()).compareTo((String) object1.getName());
//            }
//        };
//        Collections.sort(data, comparator);
//        notifyDataSetChanged();
//    }
//
//    /** Sort shopping list by date ascending */
//    public void sortByTipoAsc() {
//        Comparator<User> comparator = new Comparator<User>() {
//
//            @Override
//            public int compare(User object1, User object2) {
//                return ((String) object1.getTipoIng()).compareTo((String) object2.getTipoIng());
//            }
//        };
//        Collections.sort(data, comparator);
//        notifyDataSetChanged();
//    }
//
//    /** Sort shopping list by date descending */
//    public void sortByTipoDesc() {
//        Comparator<User> comparator = new Comparator<User>() {
//
//            @Override
//            public int compare(User object1, User object2) {
//                return ((String) object2.getTipoIng()).compareTo((String) object1.getTipoIng());
//            }
//        };
//        Collections.sort(data, comparator);
//        notifyDataSetChanged();
//    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    /** Helper class acting as a holder of the information for each row */
    private class ViewHolder {
        public CheckBox cbView;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView qty_risc;
        public TextView qty_ing;
    }
}
```

I would like to sum the value signed by red and put the result in the bottom textview

[view image](http://s22.postimg.org/t1hto7xq9/ask_1.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [Check List](https://github.com/abhishekdabral/checklist), it is demonstrating the same scenario [List with checks showing sum of the checked]

Answer (score 0):

In your ItemsListAdapterRct declare int val

```
int totalChecked = 0;
```

then in your onCheckedChanged

```
if(isChecked){
   totalChecked+=1;
}else if(totalChecked!=0){
   totalChecked-=1;
}
```

And write this function to your onCheckedChanged

```
public int getTotalChecked(){
   return totalChecked;
}
```

then call it when you need;

Comment: ok, but is possible to show the total in another textview outside the listview row, I have modify my question and updated.